# For every $k\ge 1$, exists $10^{k-1}\le n<10^k$ such that $10^k|n^2-n$?

Tags: number-theory, induction

Show that for every integer $k\ge 1$, exists an integer $n$ with $10^{k-1}\le n<10^k$ such that $10^k|n^2-n$.

In other words, for every $k\ge1$, exists an integer $n$ with $k$ digits such that the last $k$ digits of $n^2$ is the same of the $n$.

Comment: Don't be so lazy. You didn't even ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 and 25 show that
this is true for
k=1 and 2.
It also seems true that
the units digit
is always 5.

It looks like
we just have to
add a high-order digit,
so let's see is that works.

Suppose $n$ works for $k$,
so that
$10^k | (n^2-n)
=n(n-1)$,
or
$n^2-n = m10^k$.

If the new
high-order digit is $d$,
then
the new number is
$n_1 = 10^{k}d+n$
and
$10^{k+1} | (n_1^2-n_1)$.

Let
$n_1^2-n_1=m_110^{k+1}$.
This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
m_110^{k+1}
&=n_1^2-n_1\\
&=(10^{k}d+n)^2-(10^{k}d+n)\\
&=10^{2k}d^2+2nd 10^{k}+n^2-10^{k}d-n)\\
&=10^{2k}d^2+d10^{k}(2n-1)+n^2-n\\
&=10^{k}(10^{k}d^2+d(2n-1))+m10^k\\
&=10^{k}(10^{k}d^2+d(2n-1)+m)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if we can choose $d$
so that
if 
$10 | (10^{k}d^2+d(2n-1)+m))$,
we can do the induction step.

This is the same as
$10 | (d(2n-1)+m))$.

When $k=1$,
$n=5$
so that
$10m=25-5 = 20$
so $m = 2$.
The induction step requires
$10 |(9d+2)$,
so that $d = 2$ works
and the next number is $25$.

Every odd number except 5
has an inverse mod 10:
the inverses of
1, 3, 7, 9
are 1, 7, 3, 9.

Since
$n \equiv 5 \bmod 10$,
$2n-1 \not\equiv 5 \bmod 10$,
so that
$2n-1$ has an inverse
mod 10, so we can solve
$d(2n-1)+m
\equiv 0 \bmod 10
$,
so the induction step can proceed.

There is probably
a more direct way to do this.
Maybe write
$n = 10u+5$
with
$m10^k = (10u+5)(10u+4)
$ so that
$5^k | 10u+5$
and
$2^k | 10u+4$.

But this works.